# How to determine Ajax (XHR) request sender?

Tags: javascript, ajax, flash, monitoring, xmlhttprequest

Is there a way in any browser to find out who (which piece of code) actually sent an Ajax request? What I mean: in firebug one can monitor network activity (in the Net tab) but there is no way of guessing where the request was initiated from.

Does anybody know firefox/firebug extensions or maybe other browser's extensions to show request source (whether it is javascript code in particular file at particular line or browser plugin — Flash/Silverlight/etc)?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there exists any plugin that could tell you which line of code initiated the request .That would kill the entire joy of debugging :) 
Firebug tells you the URL that are being called , you can then do some relevant searches in you js code to narrow down the places and assign break points to them . This is how I generally trace .

Comment: Actually, I even don't know whether JavaScript or Flash is making the request. Moreover, JavaScript code is obfuscated ((

Comment: Yep, you are right about "joy of debugging" =) I had to decompile all the SWFs and finally found a place where the request was initiated.